# Can I match in a context and then include other contexts in an asterisk dialplan?

Tags: asterisk

I'm wondering how I should go about running some applications in the current context, and then switching to another context (as if it had been included).

So, for example, I have several contexts for incoming calls but, for one in particular, I need to perform some extra actions (specifically, I need to `Answer()` it and delay it for a second).  So, suppose that I had something like this:

```
[main-context]
include => this
include => that

[special-context]
exten => s,1,Agi(agi://<whatever>}
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
 same => n,Wait(1)
include => main-context
```

What I'd like is for calls coming in to `special-context` to get `Answer()`ed and then `main-context` included, as if the extension hadn't been matched in `special-context`.

(I am already using the `s`-extension, as shown, but that seems to run in parallel to the normal execution of the extension anyway, so I don't think that would help.)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use goto command.

```
[special-context]
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
exten => _X.,2,Goto(main-context,${EXTEN},1)
```

P.S. I higly recommend you read any single asterisk book, for example ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony"

Comment: Thank you, this works!  I had assumed that you couldn't `Goto()` priority 1, because that isn't explicitly defined in `main-context`.  But you can!

Comment: Doesn't metter. You even can do goto to goto -> result core hangs in forever loop. It not check in any variant. IF you have no destination extension, it will just say "no extension XXXX in context YYY" and do congestion or go "i" extension is that defined.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
[special-context]
exten => s,1,Agi(agi://<whatever>}
exten => _X.,1,Answer()
 same => n,Wait(1)
 same => n,Dial(Local/${EXTEN}@main-context)
```

According to [the manual](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+local+channels), this calls a pseudo-channel (chan_local), which places a call back in to the dialplan.

I'm starting up an AGI interface (in the `s`-extension) as well, and it should be noted that the extra `Dial()` interferes with the signalling that you receive on the AGI interface.  For me, the [solution posted by arheops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22025526/424221) worked much better.